# ubuntu in virtual box cannot run apt-get update

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I'm a very newbie and still learning...sory for bothering... please help me...
i just installed ubuntu-17.04-desktop-i386.iso in my virtual box. but when i try to update by

[This is the error preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2v9y.jpg)
it works just fine in my friends pc or notebook.. but not in mine;
Also when i try to open the web browser (mozilla firefox) in that ubuntu it is not working.. i have connect it with internet but it seems that in the ubuntu can't get the internet network.. but outside the virtual box it is working

do u guys have any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Probably need to configure vitual box to use the hosts network connection. Also try installing the 'guest addons' cd from virtual box UI

Answer (score 2):

Check your network settings:
Click settings and verify you have them setup[image: Virtual Box Networking Window]

NAT should be set by default, you can also use Bridged, but you probably want to avoid others

I've just started a CentOS VM and it doesn't pick up a network by default.

Make sure you have assigned a networking within the OS

Add an address or setup DHCP

Comment: it is already worked and connected to internet but now the problem is some package cannot be upgrade... do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Thanks this solved my problem after finding another tutorial that used a Host only connection!

Answer (score 0):

Go to *Settings* -> *Network* -> *Attached To* and change it to *Bridged Adapter*

I had it set to *NAT* and could not get apt-get update to work at all.